# Sql Query help needed for product relation

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have one product table with following info.

```
ID ProductId Name OtherData

1  0           A    data1
2  0           B    data2
3  1           A1   NULL
4  1           A2   NULL
```

I need all data with detail ProductId is relationship with ID column.

I need result like below

```
ID ProductId Name OtherData

1  0           A    data1
2  0           B    data2
3  1           A1   data1
4  1           A2   data1
```

What kind of join or query I should use?

Comment: How are you determining the match for the third and fourth rows?

Comment: I need otherdata from its related rows with productid

Comment: On the third and fourth rows, the productid is 1.  These rows contain no value of "data1".  So, I ask the question again:  how do you determine that you want "data1"?  Do you just want to turn all NULLs into "data1"?

Comment: It's related product. and I need to display on product detail page with all detail and same on listing page. for all detail.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT s.ID, s.ProductId, s.Name, 
  OtherData = COALESCE(s.OtherData, r.OtherData)
FROM dbo.Products AS s
LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.Products AS r
ON s.ProductId = r.ID;
```